# Why springboot not calling the jasper compiler and render jsp?

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat9

I tried with enormous efforts with all versions but still springboot not calling the jasper compiler and render jsp. Is there anyway to force springboot? Here's the output:

```
DEBUG No matching bean found for view name 'txt/register'<br/>
2022-02-19T09:58:21.037-0800 DEBUG Invoking afterPropertiesSet() on bean with name 'txt/register'<br/>
2022-02-19T09:58:21.037-0800 DEBUG Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor'<br/>
2022-02-19T09:58:21.037-0800 DEBUG Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor'<br/>
2022-02-19T09:58:21.051-0800 TRACE Cached view [txt/register]<br/>
2022-02-19T09:58:21.051-0800 DEBUG Rendering view [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView: name 'txt/register'; URL [/WEB-INF/view/txt/register.jsp]] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'<br/>
2022-02-19T09:58:21.052-0800 TRACE Rendering view with name 'txt/register' with model {signupForm=bean.txt.model.SignupForm@7464edf8, <br/>org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.signupForm=org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 0 errors, SignupForm=bean.txt.model.SignupForm@1f38a9f8, org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.SignupForm=org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 0 errors} and static attributes {}
2022-02-19T09:58:21.052-0800 DEBUG Added model object 'signupForm' of type [bean.txt.model.SignupForm] to request in view with name 'txt/register'
2022-02-19T09:58:21.052-0800 DEBUG Added model object <br/>'org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.signupForm' of type [org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult] to request in view with name 'txt/register'
2022-02-19T09:58:21.052-0800 DEBUG Added model object 'SignupForm' of type [bean.txt.model.SignupForm] to request in view with name 'txt/register'
2022-02-19T09:58:21.052-0800 DEBUG Added model object <br/>'org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.SignupForm' of type [org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult] to request in view with name 'txt/register'
2022-02-19T09:58:21.054-0800 DEBUG Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'requestDataValueProcessor'<br/>
2022-02-19T09:58:21.075-0800 DEBUG Forwarding to resource [/WEB-INF/view/txt/register.jsp] in InternalResourceView 'txt/register'<br/>
2022-02-19T09:58:21.076-0800 DEBUG Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher <br/>org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@744b7b8c
2022-02-19T09:58:21.076-0800 DEBUG SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.<br/>
2022-02-19T09:58:21.076-0800 TRACE Removed value [org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerHolder@52a0e2ad] for key [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean@44e8d9dc] from thread [http-nio-8080-exec-1]
2022-02-19T09:58:21.076-0800 DEBUG Closing JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
2022-02-19T09:58:21.076-0800 DEBUG Closing JPA EntityManager
```

M.

Comment: What makes you think the request is **not** redirected to the JSP page? Cf. _"DEBUG Forwarding to resource [/WEB-INF/view/txt/register.jsp] in InternalResourceView 'txt/register'"_

Comment: It did but display 404, I am not sure why it couldn't compile and render the jsp.  @Piotr P. Karwasz

Comment: 404 is thrown, when a resource does not exist. Is there a `/WEB-INF/view/txt/register.jsp` resource in your project? (usually it should be in `src/webapp/WEB-INF/view/txt/register.jsp`)

Comment: Yes, its working now. I used both mapping in application.properties and ViewResolver, somehow there's a typo due to exhaustive down sizing the big project.  @Piotr P. Karwasz